# WebFlux: How to retrieve AuthenticationPrincipal inside non-suspending @Controller methods

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-webflux, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I have a reactive coroutines based Spring Boot WebFlux application.
One of `@Controllers` methods returns a `Flow<Items>`; so the method cannot be marked with `suspend`. Also, am generating `openapi` interfaces and the controllers are inheriting that interface. So I cannot inject `@AuthenticationPrincipal` in @Controller Methods.

Now I have a `@Getmapping` method like this

```
override fun getItems(): ResponseEntity<Flow<Item>> {
    val CURRENTUSER = ReactiveSecurityContextHolder
        .getContext()
        .map { it.authentication.principal as String }.awaitFirst()

    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK)
      .body(service.findAll(CURRENTUSER))
}
```

Because of the use of `awaitFirst()`, code won't compile with the error - "Suspend function 'awaitFirst' should be called only from a coroutine or another suspend function"

How to retrieve current user in this scenario?

This is what fixed the issue - but is that the correct approach or are there any better alernatives?

```
override fun getItems(): ResponseEntity<Flow<Item>> =
  ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(
    flow {
      val CURRENTUSER =
        ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext()
          .map { it.authentication.principal as String }
          .awaitFirst()

      emitAll(service.findAll(CURRENTUSER))
    }
  )
```

Comment: just use more map/flatMap functions, `return Something.map( .. ).map( .. ).map( .. )`

Comment: Yes, it is correct approach.